# Map Annotations in iOS 6 don't stay rotated when user pans the map

Tags: ios, iphone

Would really love an answer to this question https://devforums.apple.com/message/723468. I can't post the details because its about iOS 6 and is Confidential per Apple.

Please post the answers/comments to the Apple Dev forums post and let me know about it here.

**EDIT: Since iOS6 is officially released:**

In my pre-ios6 code I'm doing this to rotate the map when the user location moves:

```
//this is in my MKMapViewDelegate
-(void) rotateMap:(MKMapView *)mapViewTmp forLocation:(MKUserLocation *) userLocation {
     ...
     //calculate needed rotation
     ...
     [mapViewTmp setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(lastRotation)]; //rotate the MKMapView

     for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapViewTmp.annotations) {
           MKAnnotationView* annotationView =[mapViewTmp viewForAnnotation:annotation];

                    [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-lastRotation)];      //counter rotate the Annotation Views

                    [annotationView setNeedsDisplay];  //ios6
     }

}
```

And this worked fine (1000s of users).

In ios6 however (I updated Xcode/sdk on 9/4/2012), the annotation views do not maintain this rotation (for example if map is panned). They flip back to their non rotated state (which, since my map is rotated means they show text at an angle instead of horizontal).

The code does temporarily rotate the annotations so their text appears horizontal, but if map is panned (and their seem to be other causes as well) then the annotations flip to their non-rotated state and my annotation text appears at an angle relative to the rotated map.

What is the correct way to rotate an MKAnnotationView so that it stays rotated in IOS6? What has changed in MKMapView that caused the change?

Comment: If you can't post details in the question because of the NDA, how would we post details in an answer? :)

Comment: Post the details in the Apple Dev forums. You can post an answer here, just saying "see the reply I posted" if you want the stack points for the answer.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same issue. Transforms I apply to MKAnnotationView objects are being removed when the user pans or scales the image. I've filed a bug report with Apple Dev and replied to your forum post. I'll let you know if/when I find an answer. Major regression, I've been doing this successfully since iOS 3.0.

Comment: Unfortunately the Apple Developer forums can be very tumbleweed after the excitement of an initial beta.

Comment: And the fix is===>in viewForAnnotation method: if(is6orMore) {
        [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.001)]; //iOS6 BUG WORKAROUND !!!!!!!
    }

Comment: Great, thanx! +1 You should post the answer and accept it. The only down side of this approach is: callout is also rotated. Grrr. This also happens in previous versions of iOS of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix for this is to do the following in the viewForAnnotation method:

```
// iOS6 BUG WORKAROUND !!!!!!!
if (is6orMore) {
     [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.001)]; //any small positive rotation
}
```

This was posted as a comment by me in the original question and then posted by cristis as an answer (referencing my comment), but I'm posting and accepting my own answer since it was me that came up with it. Did that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

This was posted as a comment, I'm re-posting it as an answer so anyone can see it easily (and waste less time trying to figure it out).

> And the fix is===>in viewForAnnotation method:
>
> ```
> // iOS6 BUG WORKAROUND !!!!!!!
> if (is6orMore) {
>      [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.001)]; 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same thing.  Here's the fix:

Set YOUR transform on the child of the MKAnnotationView, so in pseudo-ish code:

```
view.child.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.3);
```

Let them have control of the annotation view and take control of your view subtree.  Transforms concatenate and you'll inherit whatever they do in position.  Works for me on iOS 6.