# ios6 MKMapView deselection bug

Tags: iphone, ios6, mkmapview

I observed a strange behavior with the map in iOS 6.
Here is a code which adds a single annotation, absolutely nothing else in the project:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MKPointAnnotation * p = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    p.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10);
    p.title  = @" test test";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:p];
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = p.coordinate;
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView * p = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"wassup" ];
    p.canShowCallout = YES;
    p.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    return p;
}
```

When it is selected and I move (pan) the map small distances like 0.5-1 cm, on iOS6 the annotation gets deselected. On earlier versions works as expected and remains selected.

Is it a bug ? Is there any workaround for this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Any news on this question? I'm having similar behavior when I call setCenterCoordinate:animated: on my mapView.

Comment: Nope ... Didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Apple maps are full of bugs.. LOL you noticed that too.. 
Its a feature of iOS 6 sometime can irritate the the user.. :)

in annotaionView method use:

```
// iOS6 BUG WORKAROUND !!!!!!!
if (is6orMore) {
     [annotationView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.001)]; //any small positive rotation
}
```

Also see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324765/map-annotations-in-ios-6-dont-stay-rotated-when-user-pans-the-map)

Comment: I have to agree about the bugs :) But this doesn't solve my problem. I put this line in the `viewForAnnotation` and it still gets deselected when i move a bit the map any direction :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not deselect an annotation view, you should subclass MKAnnotationView and override the setSelected:animated: method and stop the annotation view from being deselected.